# Why can't SignalR model passed to client be parsed like JSON?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, signalr

It was hard to word the question, so let's hope my detailed explanation is better!

I have a SignalR set up where I have a struct I'm passing to the client each time the game board updates.

That object is:

```
public struct updateModelMini
    {
        public bool isMatchupOver;
        public int Player1Wins;
        public int Player2Wins;
        public TimeSpan timeLeft;
    }
```

of which updateModelMini can be parsed on the client side like a JSON object:

```
updateBoardModel.isMatchupOver
etc...
```

The problem is that I can't seem to recognize the "parts" of the System.Timespan object provided by .Net

Where

```
updateModelMini.timeLeft.TimeLeft
```

returns: **00:00:15**

```
updateModelMini.timeLeft.TimeLeft.Seconds
```

...returns as *undefined*

I'm sure there's a simple trick here to get the object exposed to the Hub and consequently the client, but I can't seem to find it via Google...

Do I need to create my own [public] object model to store the TimeSpan object? 
Anyone encountered this?

Comment: And... Yes...I know a simple solution would be to split the string on ':' and just take the last index of the returned array, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: @dandavis, would I JSONify the whole object or just the TimeSpan?

Comment: just as much as you need.

Comment: @TomO An option is to create a string property and simply place the content you need from the Timespan in that object.

Comment: @TomO Just type this and see the real json object you get at client site  `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new updateModelMini(){ timeLeft = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(66)} );` It is a **string** in the form "HH:mm:ss"